What the edge bevel does utility knife blades have?
What the edge bevel does utility knife blades have?

I couldn't find it online.

Snapping off pieces is cheaper than your time trying to sharpen it.

Well, it so happens that all the dollar stores that I used to buy the blades from stopped carrying just the blade themselves & are all selling them together with the holding knives, making them pricier. So, what am I gonna do with extra knife holders? Throw them away everytime?

How much do you pay for them?

Put spare blades in the extra folders and leave 'em where convenient. I have some in the kitchen for opening packages, some in the workshop, some in the household repair toolbox, some with supplies for crafts which need them. Avoids chasing all over the house for one.

This isn't really a home improvement question, so it is likely to be closed, but:
It isn't hard to make a blade angle gauge. It can be as simple as printing out a set of angles on a PC, cutting them out, and inserting the blade to see which "V"  lines up best with the blade's faces.
A few degrees either way makes very little difference.
And if you are sharpening by hand, you can often determine the angle by touch, or close enough not to matter -- it's the one at which the bevel rests most solidly on the sharpening medium.
Though realistically, even if you wind up with extra handes, there are designed to be cheap enough to be disposable and when you figure the value of your time and effort are probably not worth sharpening. If you want to try anyway, go for it, but I suspect you will reconsider pretty quickly.
Of course the version at left, the non-breakaway utility knife blade, is widely available in packs of 10-100. Websearch will easily find suppliers, or walk into any home center or most hardware stores.
But if you really want to know... It probably varies by manufacturer, and quite possibly by product line. If you care that much, I would suggest taking a vernier caliper or a micrometer to samples of the blades you use. Measuring the blade's thickness, and the height of the tapered section, should let you calculate the angle of the edge. Obviously, the calculation will be slightly different depending on whether the blade is sharpened from both sides as an isosceles cross section, or sharpened from one side as a right triangle cross section, but either is easy high school geometry and a scientific calculator may actually solve for it for you.
I hope you'll forgive me if I leave that as an exercise for the reader. I don't have samples of your blades, and I'm just not that interested.
